# Is there a way to hide blue borderline on focused pane in Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-terminal

When I zoom to pane I see this blue borderline. Is there a way to hide it?
[image: Before zooming]

[image: After zooming]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Terminal 1.13, there isn't - that's just part of the UI to help indicate that you have a pane zoomed.

[microsoft/terminal#3063](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3063) is tracking adding a setting to the Terminal to configure the border width, and [microsoft/terminal#30631](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3061) is tracking adding support for changing the color. I'd go upvote those two if you're interested in such a setting.